# creating unique web pages from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I'm very new to web development (I have limited experience with HTML). I'm creating a debate website. Currently, each debate is stored in a MySQL database. When the user submits the information to the database, I want a new page to be created, that contains their debate, and the ability to comment and rate it.

The problem I'm having is that, from the research I've done so far, I'm not finding a solution to having a new web page for each debate. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to write the data to a unique web page??

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you are using PHP and MySQL.

I will keep this very simple as possible probably need these files in a basic example plus your hopefull explanatory SQL tables (debates, comments, etc).

- /debatelist.php | Dipslays all debateshas a form to create a debate
- /debateprocessor.php | Your 'all in one' data manipulation file.
- /debate_detail.php | Your detail page where the index of debates points to.

**Form to CREATE A DEBATE**

```
<form action='debateprocessor.php' action='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='create'/>
<input type='text name='debate_name'/>
/// Other inputs - debate topic, debate author, subject etc? same as above
</form>
```

then that would send the form data to debateprocessor.php where we'd sanitize and prepit.

$_GET['action']="create" #this tells us we are creating the a debate
$_GET['debate_name']="SomeDebate"

**debateprocessor.php** - you'd want to to pull that in:

```
if (mysql_real_escape_text($_GET['action'])) == 'create'){
    $debate_name = mysql_real_escape_text($_GET['debate_name']);
    //sanitize other variables as above

    //Insert debate name
    mysql_query=("INSERT INTO debates (debate_id,debate_name) VALUES ('$debate_name'");

}
```

Note the action if($action == 'foo'){ //do something; } statement - this would allow you to handle updates (comments, editing debate names etc) all in one file. other values for action in forms could be 'edit', 'add_comment' etc - you could have separate files to do all this but this allows you to do it all one. All you'd do is add on elseifs or other if statements like above for each action to modify a table.

So displaying your debates you'd have something like a master list of debates in a table, say you had

**debatelist.php**

```
<?
$getDebates = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM debates";); 
$rowNum = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getDebates))
{
    $thisDebate = $row['debate_name'];
    $thisDebateID = $row['debate_id'];;

    echo
    "
        <tr>
        <td>
           <a href='debate_detail.php?debateid=$thisDebateID'>
            $thisDebate
        </a>
        </td>

    </tr>
    ";
    $rowNum++;
}
```

That would output a list of debate names with a link to ea. debate_detail.php page for a given debate pulled by the PK, debate ID. In that file you'd use a similar combination of SELECT (ONLY USE 'WHERE debate_id = 'xyz' and would likely JOIN tables like comments etc on debate_id='zyx' = debate_id='zyx'.

Comment: How do you call the query on the `debate_detail.php` page? When someone clicks on the link of `<a href='debate_detail.php?debateid=$thisDebateID'>`, how do you get the value of `$thisDebateID` so that you can call `SELECT * WHERE debate_id = $thisDebateID`

Answer (score 1):

Have a script that looks at the requested URI (the query string is the simplest place to look `foo.php?debate=1` → `$_GET['debate']`) and use that to get a piece of information that uniquely identifies the debate you want (e.g. the value of the column you use for the primary key in the database table).

Look up that row in the database, and output the content to the page.

(Make sure you send data to the database in a way that defends against SQL Injection, and that you don't echo user input back to the HTML without escaping or sanitising it to defend against XSS).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a templating engine such as PHP.  For each debate you pass a different query string for example for debate id 1 you might have

```
www.example.com/debates?id=1
```

In your php code you can then check the value of this query parameter and use it to extract the corrwect information from the databse, allowing you to dynamically create the page.

Comment: So I pass the different query strings in my original debates form? Or can I get the value of each debate from the ID in the database?